# why does View.setLayoutParams can call ViewGroup.onSetLayoutParams which is protected?

Tags: android, android-layout, layoutparams

when i was searching the android source code, i have found something i can not understand or bear. you can see all onSetLayoutParams in the frameworks source code bellow:

**./base/core/java/android/widget/Toolbar.java:    protected void onSetLayoutParams(View child, ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp) {**

**./base/core/java/android/widget/GridLayout.java:    protected void onSetLayoutParams(View child, ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams) {**

**./base/core/java/android/widget/GridLayout.java:        super.onSetLayoutParams(child, layoutParams);**

**./base/core/java/android/view/View.java:            ((ViewGroup) mParent).onSetLayoutParams(this, params);**

**./base/core/java/android/view/ViewGroup.java:    protected void onSetLayoutParams(View child, LayoutParams layoutParams) {**

every define of onSetLayoutParams is proected, yet View.setLayoutParams cast its parent to a ViewGroup, then call ViewGroup's onSetLayoutParams. i don not think this is right in java, but all android seems running very well.

sorry for my poor english.

Comment: The method is protected, but I can't access it from a inherited class. =/

Comment: Because it's marked @hide it's not included in the SDK and not included in android.jar (so you cannot override or call it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

somehow i found my answer from this page: [In Java, difference between default, public, protected, and private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private)

Java protected seems making the method not visible to classes out of this package, within the same package, its a public method.